How can I toggle the theme dynamically?
I started to learn React-Native and I would like to code a small program that only changes dynamically the theme.
I wrote three files:

App.js (Main file)
./contexts/theme-context.js (context for the theme)
./screens/Login.jsx (dummy login screen that contains the button to toggle the theme)

I tried different ways but I didn't succeed to make that theme change. I tried to modify the useEffect hook inside App.js but it ignores changes from the context coming from the toggle button inside the Login Screen.
PS: I use the paper library (https://reactnativepaper.com/)
App.js
import {ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import LoginScreen from "./screens/LoginScreen";
import {
    DarkTheme as NavigationDarkTheme,
    DefaultTheme as NavigationDefaultTheme,
    NavigationContainer,
} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
    MD3DarkTheme,
    MD3LightTheme,
    adaptNavigationTheme,
    PaperProvider,
} from 'react-native-paper';
import ThemeContextProvider, {ThemeContext} from "./contexts/theme-context";
import merge from 'deepmerge';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const {LightTheme, DarkTheme} = adaptNavigationTheme({
    reactNavigationLight: NavigationDefaultTheme,
    reactNavigationDark: NavigationDarkTheme,
});
const CombinedDefaultTheme = merge(MD3LightTheme, LightTheme);
const CombinedDarkTheme = merge(MD3DarkTheme, DarkTheme);

export default function App() {

    const {setTheme, theme} = useContext(ThemeContext);

    const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function init() {
            const isDarkTheme = await AsyncStorage.getItem("isDark");
            setTheme(isDarkTheme ? CombinedDarkTheme : CombinedDefaultTheme);
            setAppIsReady(true);
        }

        init();

    }, []);

    if (!appIsReady) {
        return <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>
    }

    return (
        <ThemeContextProvider>
            <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
                <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
                    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{}}>
                        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen}/>
                    </Stack.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
            </PaperProvider>
        </ThemeContextProvider>
    );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

LoginScreen.jsx
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from "react-native";
import {Button} from "react-native-paper";
import {useContext} from "react";
import {ThemeContext} from "../contexts/theme-context";

function LoginScreen() {
    const {theme, toggleTheme} = useContext(ThemeContext);
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Button onPress={() => {
                    toggleTheme()
                }}>Press me Theme -> {theme.dark ? "Dark" : "Light"}</Button>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

export default LoginScreen;


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,

    },
});

theme-context.js
import {createContext, useState} from 'react'
import {adaptNavigationTheme, MD3DarkTheme, MD3LightTheme} from "react-native-paper";
import {DarkTheme as NavigationDarkTheme, DefaultTheme as NavigationDefaultTheme} from "@react-navigation/native";
import merge from "deepmerge";

const {LightTheme, DarkTheme} = adaptNavigationTheme({
    reactNavigationLight: NavigationDefaultTheme,
    reactNavigationDark: NavigationDarkTheme,
});
const CombinedDefaultTheme = merge(MD3LightTheme, LightTheme);
const CombinedDarkTheme = merge(MD3DarkTheme, DarkTheme);


export const ThemeContext = createContext({
    theme: CombinedDefaultTheme,
    setTheme: () => {
    },
    toggleTheme: () => {
    }
});


function ThemeContextProvider({children}) {

    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(CombinedDefaultTheme);

    function toggleTheme() {
        setTheme(theme.dark ? CombinedDefaultTheme : CombinedDarkTheme)
    }

    return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={{theme, setTheme, toggleTheme}}>{children}</ThemeContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default ThemeContextProvider;

-- Edit
It works if I move the whole content of App.js in another composent, let says Main.js. In the Main.js I only removed the ThemeContextProvider wrapper.
And then my App.js becomes:
import Main from "./Main";
import ThemeContextProvider from "./contexts/theme-context";


export default function App() {

    return (
        <ThemeContextProvider>
            <Main/>
        </ThemeContextProvider>
    );
}

I don't really understand why I needed to do that for making it work
